# Reactjs dropdown component from primefaces installation issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, primereact

I am new to Reactjs and I would like to use [this kind of dropdown](https://bit.dev/primefaces/primereact/dropdown) in my app. There is mentioned as:-

npm i @bit/primefaces.primereact.dropdown . When I do so I get following error:-

> npm ERR! code E404 npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/@bit%2fprimefaces.primereact.dropdown - Not
>   found npm ERR! 404  npm ERR! 404 
>   '@bit/primefaces.primereact.dropdown@latest' is not in the npm
>   registry. npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use
>   the name yourself!) npm ERR! 404  npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also
>   install from a npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

How do I install it and us this in my app?

Comment: Sure this is PrimeFACES related? I strongly doubt it. Click the PrimeFaces tag and read it.

Comment: I just don't see that package in the npm registry.

Comment: can you suggest any other similar component that I can use in my reactjs  app?

Comment: @masiboo I don't know what specifically you want from that dropdown/select component/package, but there are [tons of alternatives](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=select). `React-Select` is really common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how your install `primereact` in your React App: `npm install primereact --save`
and then import whatever you want like this:

`import {Dropdown} from 'primereact/dropdown';`

Make sure to install its dependencies and peer dependencies: `react-transition-group`, `classnames`, `primeicons`

Check this out.: https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/setup

and this : https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/dropdown